# Why did sshd delete my /dev/zero?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, devices, sshd, file-descriptors

When I do `lsof +c 0 | grep /dev/zero`, I see the following two lines:

```
sshd    19064    root  DEL    REG    0,4    497862    /dev/zero
sshd    19064    root  DEL    REG    0,4    498725    /dev/zero
```

The **DEL** keyword is what intrigues me - from the manpages, it means:

> *DEL* for a Linux map file that has been deleted

However, last time I checked my `/dev/zero` was still there, even if I reboot... So why would *sshd* attempt to delete this character device and why would it even succeed given that:

- It is a character device, not a file
- it is owned by root

**OS info:** `Linux localhost 3.4.103 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 18 13:07:12 CST 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux` *(Arch Linux)*

Comment: I would interpret the `DEL` flag as "The file opened and the file on disk are not the same", i.e. manipulating the file on disk will not influence the process. At least that makes sense for `/dev/zero`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DEL` doesn't indicate that *that process* deleted `/dev/zero`, but that that process is using `/dev/zero` and the instance of `/dev/zero` that was being used has since been deleted. For example, if I have a command (say `some-command`) that uses `/some/file` and I do:

```
$ some-command &
$ rm /some/file
$ touch /some/file
```

Then `lsof` for `/some/file` would look like:

```
some-command    ...    ...  DEL    ...    ...    ...    /some/file
```

The contents of the deleted file continue to remain on disk until the process lets go or is killed, but won't be directly accessible.

The version of `/some/file` that I created using `touch` is not the one that `some-command` is using.

Comment: Okay, that helps a lot... However, should it then not show this for each process that ever read something from `/dev/zero`? It's a stream of characters and each process could potentialy read different amount of them, thus having a "different version" of it. Alternatively, how can anyone know when such a device has changed, or even change it (since writing to it behaves identically to writing to `/dev/null`)? Or, does this simply mean that perhaps *sshd* did not close the file descriptor yet (or some such thing), thus showing on the list...?

Comment: @RobertRossmann The last is correct. `sshd` opened `/dev/zero`, `/dev/zero` got deleted, `sshd` has not yet closed the fd. The kernel knows, since it keeps track of fds and what the fd points to. Notice that in my example, `some-command` is sent to the background, so it would (presumably) still be running when I deleted and ran `lsof`.

Comment: Great, I am starting to understand.:) It still implies, though, that `/dev/zero` got somehow modified while *sshd* was using it - how could such thing happen if, when written to, does nothing and when read from, returns the same data (albeit a variable length)? How does the kernel determine that the file has changed? PS. Writing to it does not change *mtime*...

Comment: Yes, writing to it doesn't change any of its times, but any process running as root can delete and recreate it (`sudo mknod /dev/zero c 1 5`). The kernel can know when a file is accessed, written to, modified, deleted, etc. - that's why [`inotify`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/inotify.7) is possible.

Comment: As to what deleted it, who knows? That will be hard to discover.

Comment: And for how the kernel can know, note that any access is made using system calls. The kernel handles those, and is the arbiter here. It shouldn't be that difficult for it to know when a particular system call was made, by whom and for what.

Comment: Great, I feel I understand now. Thanks for your help! Let's see if I can track down what changed my `/dev/zero`. Just FYI, it seems to happen every time a new ssh session is opened - more and more `DEL` entries appear in the `lsof` output.

Comment: @RobertRossmann might be some security measure. But I can't figure out how `sshd` opens `/dev/zero` - there's no indication in `strace` output.

Comment: I strongly suspect the conclusion "something deleted `/dev/zero` while sshd had it open" is false; on a small selection of systems I tested, `/dev/zero` _always_ had the `DEL` flag. I suspect this is either a side effect of how the kernel handles `/dev/zero`, or a deliberate optimization (perhaps to discard writes to it in an early stage).